# Lag lengths are larger than my domain in gstat in R? variogram object

Tags: r, spatial, variogram

My problem is that the my resulting variograms are of a larger lag length than my domain.

I have the following code to compute lags in the vertical direction:

```
x = rep(sample(1:300,10),each=4)
y = rep(sample(1:300,10),each=4)
z = sample(seq(0,30),40,replace=T)
K = sample(seq(-1,1,0.01),40,replace=T)

mydata = data.frame(x,y,z,K)

# compute lags in vertical direction 
h <- gstat(formula=K~1, locations=~x+y+z, data=mydata)
raw.vgm <- variogram(h,alpha=0,tol.hor=180,beta=0,tol.ver=5)
plot(raw.vgm,main='X-Y Variogram of Well')
plot(raw.vgm$dist,raw.vgm$gamma)  # plot variogram manually because of warning
```

Notice that the minimum and maximum value  for z, i.e. the vertical direction is as follows:

```
> max(mydata$z)
    [1] 30
    > min(mydata$z)
[1] 1
>
```

However, the variogram shows lengths up to 120 meters, even though the maximum length is 30, as shown above.  I set the vertical tolerance to 5 meters, so I do not think it is an issue of tolerance.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?  Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the "maximum length" is $30$? You are specifying x,y, and z coordinates in which the largest potential inter-point distance is (according to the Pythagorean Theorem) equal to $\sqrt{(300-1)^2 + (300-1)^2 + (30-0)^2}=424$, not $30$!

Comment: But you'll notice that the vertical tolerance is 5 degrees.  Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Correct way to do what, exactly?  Many, many considerations go into variography, even when the software will perform automatic fits for you. One primary concern when modeling 3D data is how to handle anisotropy. Especially when the domain is much smaller in the z direction, it is likely anisotropy is large. Setting a small vertical tolerance is just one part of coping with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for the `cutoff` parameter of `variogram` is one third of the maximum diagional of the bounding box spanning the data, so 424/3. You can choose other values by specifying this parameter. This is all documented.